# Arduino does not connect to MQTT local broker

Tags: arduino-mega, ethernet, mqtt

I have an Arduino Mega with Ethernet connected to a router by cable. Also I have a PC connected to the router (by Wifi) where also the local MQTT broker is installed (mosquitto). Althought the Arduino Ethernet connection seems ok, the MQTT connection does not: I get the return code -2

This is the full code, there are several functions but the MQTT init is the one that fails:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> // Librería para MQTT

byte mac[] = { 0xA8, 0x61, 0x0A, 0xAE, 0x3A, 0xC4 };
byte ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 100 };                      
byte gateway[] = { 192, 168, 1, 2 };                  
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };

EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(ethClient);

const char *MQTT_BROKER_ADRESS = "192.168.1.101";
const uint16_t MQTT_PORT = 1883;
const char *MQTT_CLIENT_NAME = "mqttx_7c0a0ed3";

void SuscribeMqtt()
{
    mqttClient.subscribe("hello/world");
}

void OnMqttReceived(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
    Serial.print("Received on ");
    Serial.print(topic);
    Serial.print(": ");
    String content = "";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        content.concat((char)payload[i]);
    }
    Serial.print(content);
    Serial.println();
}

void InitMqtt()
{
    mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_BROKER_ADRESS, MQTT_PORT);
    mqttClient.setCallback(OnMqttReceived);
}

void ConnectMqtt()
{
    Serial.print("Starting MQTT connection...");
    if (mqttClient.connect(MQTT_CLIENT_NAME))
    {
        SuscribeMqtt();
        mqttClient.publish("connected","hello/world");
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.print("Failed MQTT connection, rc=");
        Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
        Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
        delay(5000);
    }
}

void HandleMqtt()
{
    if (!mqttClient.connected())
    {
        ConnectMqtt();
    }
    mqttClient.loop();
}

void CheckLinkStatus() {
  
  auto link = Ethernet.linkStatus();
  
  Serial.print("Link status: ");
  
  switch (link) {
    case Unknown:
      Serial.println("Unknown");
      break;
    case LinkON:
      Serial.println("ON");
      break;
    case LinkOFF:
      Serial.println("OFF");
      break;
  }
  delay(1000);
}

void setup() {
  
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  //Ethernet.init(10);  // Most Arduino shields

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());

  delay(1500);
  
  InitMqtt();
  
}

// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
void loop() {

  CheckLinkStatus();

  HandleMqtt();
  
}
```

I have done ping from the PC IP (192.168.1.101) to the Arduino IP (192.168.1.100) and it is ok. What could be the issue?.

Comment: What is in the logs of the MQTT broker?

Comment: @StarCat how do I check the log file? I am not able to find it.

Comment: @StarCat maybe I can't find it because I am executing mosquitto as a service? also I am not able to modify conf file

Comment: is the port open on Firewall?

Comment: Maybe find an app you can run on a different computer or your phone to verify that you can connect into your mosquito server on the PC.

Comment: I finally found the issue! As @Juraj pointed out, there was some problem with mosquitto which was blocked by the windows 10 firewall. I am sure of this because when I executed mosquito with permissions and properly using the cmd, a windows firewall windows popped up and then I unblocked it and after that Arduino was able to connect

Comment: @timemage I have installed MQTT Explorer on the PC, it is very useful to check the traffic. Thanks!

Comment: @StarCat I was finally able to run mosquitto correctly, also I am writing now the log into a text file. In my answer I have put all the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was coming from mosquitto local broker, which was being blocked by windows 10 firewall. When I executed mosquitto with the correct permissions on its folder (read and write for "all users") and with correct mosquitto configuration file, the following window popped up and I clicked on to allow both private and public connections:

[image: n]

I also use the following batch file to load mosquitto and it works all the time:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\mosquitto"
del mosquitto.log
mosquitto -v -c mosquitto.conf
```

This is the content of my mosquitto configuration file:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_dest file C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.log
```

Now I am able to use MQTT from Arduino connected to a router.

Answer (score -1):

With a bit of research you can see that return code two is:

`2    Connection refused: client identifier not allowed by server.`

My guess is that you forgot to add the login details in the code, or the code fails because the client ID is not a c-string. Try something like this (replace with appropriate values):

`if (client.connect(clientId.c_str(), mqttUsername, mqttPassword)){`

Comment: It was a firewall isse when executing mosquitto, but thanks anyway!